# DataBinding: Adjust visibility by LiveData Variable on Click

Tags: android, android-databinding

I want to adjust the visibility of a `ProgressBar` depending on a `MutableLiveData` variable in my `ViewModel`. I learned that `MutableLiveData` does not work, so I need a `LiveData` variable to transform it... Kind of strange, but well at least it should work right?

Well it does not work at the moment. And I don't get why I want two variables to do one thing.

I hope the code speaks for itself:

**Activity:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val binding: ActivityLoginBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_login)
    binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    binding.viewmodel = vm
}
```

**View Model:**

```
class LoginViewModel : ViewModel() {
    var isLoading: MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLiveData(false)
    var showLoadingIndicator: LiveData<Boolean> = Transformations.map(isLoading) { isLoading.value }

    fun login() {
        Timber.d("login")
        isLoading.value = true
    }
}
```

**Layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <data>
        <variable
                name="viewmodel"
                type="mypackage.LoginViewModel"/>
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton        
                android:onClick="@{() -> viewmodel.login()}"/>

        <include
                layout="@layout/loading_indicator"
                app:goneUnless="@{viewmodel.showLoadingIndicator}"/>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

**BindingAdapter:**

```
@Suppress("unused")
object BindingAdapters {
    @BindingAdapter("goneUnless")
    @JvmStatic
    fun goneUnless(view: View, visible: Boolean) {
        view.visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}
```

When I click the `Button` the `Timber` call works, but the visibility of the loading indicator does not change (from `GONE` to `VISIBLE`). How can I fix this and maybe get rid of the two variables and have only one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't actually need a `BindingAdapter`, there's a simpler way to accomplish what you want.

1) ViewModel: change your loading field to: `val isLoading = ObservableBoolean()` OR `val isLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>`*

2) Add the import inside the `<data>` tag of your layout: `<import type="android.view.View"/>`

3) Your include will become:

```
<include
   layout="@layout/loading_indicator"
   android:visibility="@{viewmodel.isLoading ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"/>
```

Use `set(value)` to change the value of the `ObservableBoolean` or `setValue()` (`postValue()` if you are off the main thread) for `LiveData`.

*it is considered a good practice to expose a `LiveData` instance and keep the actual `MutableLiveData` private.

Comment: It kinda works. I had no success with the `include` tho. But when I add the `Progressbar` directly, it works. I probably screwed something in the included layout up. 
hanks a lot! It even works with the `BindingAdapter`:) 
The `ObservableBoolean` did it for me.

Comment: would you like to add your answer based on LiveData as it is advisable to replace observable field with live data

Comment: Cannot identifier VISIBLE

Comment: @ThiệnKopites you have to add `<import type="android.view.View"/>` inside the <data> block of your layout file

Comment: @chrjs  give the included layout an id else it wont work, ie 
  <include
            android:id="@+id/loading_state_layout"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.isLoading? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}"
            layout="@layout/loading_state" />

Answer (score 0):

This works great for me:

```
@BindingAdapter("android:visibility")
fun View.setVisibility(visible: Boolean?) {
    visibility = if (visible != null && visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```